# django-mptt fields showing up twice, breaking SQL

Tags: django, django-mptt

I'm using django-mptt to manage a simple CMS, with a model called `Page`, which looks like this (most presumably irrelevant fields removed):

```
class Page(mptt.Model, BaseModel):
  title    = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
  slug     = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'title')
  contents = models.TextField()
  parent   = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, 
         related_name='children', help_text = u'The page this page lives under.')
```

<sup>removed fields are called `attachments`, `headline_image`, `nav_override`, and `published`</sup>

All works fine using SQLite, but when I use MySQL and try and add a Page using the admin (or using ModelForms and the `save()` method), I get this:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/mycms/page/add/
(1110, "Column 'level' specified twice")
```

where the SQL generated is:

```
'INSERT INTO `kaleo_page` (`title`, `slug`, `contents`, `nav_override`, `parent_id`,  
`published`, `headline_image_id`, `lft`, `rght`, `tree_id`, `level`, `lft`, `rght`,    
`tree_id`, `level`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
```

for some reason I'm getting the django-mptt fields (`lft`, `rght`, `tree_id` and `level`) twice. It works in SQLite presumably because SQLite is more forgiving about what it accepts than MySQL.

`get_all_field_names()` also shows them twice:

```
>>> Page._meta.get_all_field_names()
['attachments', 'children', 'contents', 'headline_image', 'id', 'level', 'lft',
'nav_override', 'parent', 'published', 'rght', 'slug', 'title', 'tree_id']
```

Which is presumably why the SQL is bad. What could I have done that would result in those fields appearing twice in `get_all_field_names()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appeared to be that the fields were being dynamically added twice (I **think** because of the way `settings.py` is imported twice.

I ended up fixing it by using the regular version of django-mptt, and adding this to my `__init__.py`:

```
from cbc.kaleo.models import Page
import mptt

try:
    mptt.register(Page)
except mptt.AlreadyRegistered:
    pass
```

Not the prettiest thing in the world, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you're inheriting from multiple base classes, `class Page(mptt.Model, BaseModel):`.  Are the fields that are being duplicated found on both of those models?

Comment: Argh - sorry, should have removed that. No. I've tested without the multiple inheritance and get the same behaviour. That was my first guess too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a [branch of mptt](http://github.com/bfirsh/django-mptt) that allows for inheritance, lets assume that  inheriting mptt.Model is the same as using [mptt.register()](http://django-mptt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/models.txt).

```
# Page and TrunkPage are basically the same
class Page(branched_mptt.Models, BaseModel):
    # ...

class TrunkPage(BaseModel):
    # ...
trunk_mptt.register(TrunkPage, order_insertion_by=['title'])
```

Do you see duplicate fields when you run `manage.py sqlall`?  It looks OK using the branched_mptt when I run it with sqlite3 or mysql:

```
$ ./manage.py sqlall kaleo
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `kaleo_page` (
    [ ... ]
    `lft` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `rght` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tree_id` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `level` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
[ ... ]
```

If that output looks OK, what about your PageAdmin?  Are you doing anything fancy there?  If so, have you tried with a plain vanilla model admin for Page?

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from kaleo.models import Page

admin.site.register(Page)
```

Comment: Sorry - another instance of my question not being clear - I'm using Ben Firshman's fork of django-mptt (http://github.com/bfirsh/django-mptt), which uses inheritance instead of registering

Comment: Thanks for your help (and +1 for the effort!) Output of `sqlall` only shows the fields once, and I still get the error even if I just use `admin.site.register(Page)`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not much else comes to mind atm.  The only other thing I would do is try it on a fresh DB and then start adding pieces one at a time until the problem is triggered.  Not a fun or easy next step but it should help you track down the source of the problem.  Also try your kaleo app in a fresh project with it as the only app -- anything to eliminate other variables helps.